# How can I remove the tag's text with Javascript, only the text not tag

Tags: javascript

**HTML:**

```
<h2>
Available courses
    <span>Available courses</span>
</h2>
```

**SCRIPTS:**

```
var textCon1 = document.querySelector("#frontpage-course-list h2");
var textCon2 = document.querySelector("#frontpage-course-list h2").innerHTML;
var createSpan = document.createElement("span");
createSpan.innerHTML = textCon2;
textCon2.appendChild(￼createSpan);
textCon1.innerHTML="";
```

Here I am trying to remove the text available in h2 tag, but it removes everything available in h2 tag. I want to keep span tag with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple add this line, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/k0m3z8bj/)

```
textCon1.childNodes[0].textContent = "";
```

it will replace the first `text-node` with empty text.